# How to use initial fixed timestep, then decrease it according to dependent variable, while spatial stepsize is fixed

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve an advection equation. I want to force constant spatial step size (x dimension) with the “MethodOfLines” option, whereas I want to use initially fixed time step size 0.01 then decrease the time step size to be (0.001, 0.0001) when the minimum value of u(t,x) is less than (-6, -7). I tried the following code, and adopt ImplicitRungeKutta method to integrate with respect to time. I even can not set time step size in the ImplicitRungeKutta method.
I try this

```
WhenEvent[{u[t, x]<=-6}, stepsize -> 0.001];
WhenEvent[{u[t, x]<=-7}, stepsize -> 0.0001];
```

But how can I combine this event trigger in my time integration method? Anyone can help me?

```
mdfun = First[u /. NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
  0.5 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x], 
 u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi] == 0, u[0, x] == Sin[x]}, 
u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", DifferenceOrder -> 2, 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}},
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "MinPoints" -> 100, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]]
```

Then Plot it

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[mdfun[t, x]], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can set the time step:

```
mdfun = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 0.5 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x], 
u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi] == 0, u[0, x] == Sin[x], WhenEvent[u[t, Pi/2] > -.1, "StopIntegration"]}, 
u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
Method -> \
{"MethodOfLines",(*"DiscretizedMonitorVariables"->True,*)
 Method -> {"FixedStep", "StepSize" -> .5, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"},
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 100, "MaxPoints" -> 100}},
 StepMonitor :> Print[t]];
```

Uncomment the DiscretizedMonitorVariables if you want to use something like Min[u[t, x]] in WhenEvent.

But it seems you can't change the method parameters with WhenEvent. At least I don't know how. The only thing I can suggest is to write the function, which will use new ndsolve after each whenevent happens and starting with time, when last ndsolve stopped. Ask if you need such function.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful. It seems what I want. In fact, I am a MMA beginner. I have learned the use of NDSolveValue. :) You mean I can use the result given by NDSloveValue and only change the stepsize in the next run or runs. However, Sometimes I want to judge where the min value of u[t,x] exceed a certain value,say, min(u)<0.01. How can I achieve it. In addition, How can I know the exact value of min(u) when the integration just is stopped and the value of independent variable x where the min(u) is reached (although it is obvious in this equation). Thanks a lot!